# AngularJs ng-repeat orderBy toggle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

How do I change the `orderBy` filter in `ng-repeat`? The default order value is by date (most recent first), but by clicking on `toggle_to_sort()`, I need to change the sort order to by name (alphabet order), then if a user clicks again - return to order by date.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [
    {name: 'item1', date: 1453284120},
    {name: 'item2', date: 1453284440},
    {name: 'item3', date: 1453284550},
    {name: 'item4', date: 1453284086},
    {name: 'item5', date: 1453284330},
  ];
    
  $scope.toggle_to_sort = function() {
    // ??
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in array  | orderBy:'-date'">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>

  <div ng-click="toggle_to_sort()">Toggle<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",function($scope){
  

  
$scope.array = [
{name: 'item1', date: 1453284120},
{name: 'item2', date: 1453284440},
{name: 'item3', date: 1453284550},
{name: 'item4', date: 1453284086},
{name: 'item5', date: 1453284330},
]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-click="mytoggle=!mytoggle">Name<div><hr>
<div ng-repeat="item in array | orderBy: !mytoggle?'-date':'name' ">
  
 <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
</body>

  </html>
```

Hope It Will Help...

Answer (score 3):

Declare a flag

```
$scope.changeFilter=false;
```

then add this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array  | orderBy: !changeFilter ? '-date' : 'name'">
```

change the value on button click

```
<div ng-click="changeFilter=!changeFilter"><div>
```

<kbd>[**`DEMO`**](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/fn44eqkb/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In your JS I would add this:

```
$scope.toggled = false;
```

And then in your HTML do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array  | orderBy:'-date'" ng-hide="toggled">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="item in array  | orderBy:'-name'" ng-show="toggled">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
</div>

<div ng-click="toggled=!toggled"><div>
```